# WCF EF code first syncronization best practices

Tags: wcf, ef-code-first, synchronization

There is a offline WPF client and WCF server. 
Client use SQL-CE or localDB - EF-Code first

For example, for the following scenario - Administrator can edit the common information and to add jobs to Users, and the user can see the lobules added him the job, and synchronize changes made when a connection.

**Prompt the best way to synchronize reference data.** 
Looking toward the "microsoft sync framework" - but it seems that then have to implement your own provider. Maybe there's an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL CE and LocalDB are both supported out of the box in Sync Framework. you can use the same SqlSyncProvider against the LocalDb

no need to write custom sync providers.

Comment: I use EF-Code first- How can I generate service tables for microsoft sync framework tracking?

Comment: Sync Fx doesn't integrate with  EF. But there's no stopping you synching databases you use in EF using Sync Fx. likewise, Sync Fx creates more than just tables, better leave it to the provisioning to do it than you coding it via EF.

Comment: Can you provide me simple example how make provisioning via EF-code first?

Comment: as i have mentioned, provisioning is better than using the Sync Fx Provisioning API. if you want to have an idea of what it does during provisioning, try provisioning a sample table and explore the objects created or call the generate script method and have a look at the generated SQL scripts.

Comment: above should have read: "provisioning is better done using the Sync Fx Provisioning API."